# How to change content in div on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to change some content in divs on click. Found one solution, but it works only with ID. Change content of only one div. How to fix it?

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
$("#buttons a").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#pages div").css("display", "none");
    $("#pages div#" + id + "").css("display", "block");
    });});
```

Here is [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mA8hj/140/)

UPDATE.
Edited Jsfiddle a little bit. Here is picture:

[image]

Comment: $("#pages div") this is the part which changes all divs?

Comment: You can change `#idselectors` with `.classname` or `[attribute=value]` or simply `[attribute]`. You have tons of possible selectors to use in CSS / javascript

Comment: I would use classes instead of setting inline style. I did attempt to update your fiddle with an example but it is not clear exactly what is suppose to show and hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you want to change the content of multiple div's, you can do it like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/Airrudi/mA8hj/139/

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $("button").click(function() {
        var content = $(this).data('content');   
        $('#pages .allowChange p').html(content);
    });    
});
```

Can you elaborate a bit more on your question if this is not what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the first div by using :nth-child:() selector.
Read about this [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
  $("#buttons a").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#pages div:nth-child(1)").css("display", "none");
    $("#pages div#" + id + "").css("display", "block");
  });
});
```

Comment: You could use `:first` instead of `:nth-child(1)` if that's all you need

Comment: @CAbbott The question says any 1 div, so I assume it might not be the first.